# Struts 2 jquery autocompleter with JSON

Tags: json, jquery-plugins, struts2, autocomplete

I'm using atocompleter in my form with json.

This is the part of my struts.xml

```
    <package name="json" namespace="/" extends="json-default">
    <result-types>
        <result-type name="json" class="com.googlecode.jsonplugin.JSONResult" />
    </result-types>
    <action name="test" class="testClass" method="populate">
        <result type="json" name="success">
            <param name="root">itemList</param>
            <param name="contentType">text/html</param>
        </result>
    </action>
</package>
```

This is the jsp

```
        <s:form id="frm_demo" name="frm_demo" theme="simple" action="test2">
         <s:url id="remoteurl" action="test" />         
        <sj:autocompleter
                            id="lst"
                            name="lst"
                            list="%{remoteurl}"
                            listValue="name"
                            listKey="id"
                            selectBox="true"
                    /> 
                     <s:submit value="submit"/>
              </s:form>
```

This is the action class method

```
    public String populate() throws Exception{
    itemList.put("1", "a");
    itemList.put("2", "b");
    itemList.put("3", "c");
    return "success";
}
```

With the above code in struts.xml my jsp renders like this.`{"3":"c","2":"b","1":"a"}`

But when I delete the "contentType" parameter, in other words the content type is "application/json" the jsp pops the download window.
I need theauto completer to return the key when i click submit button. But the page doesn't load with the autocompleter. Any solutions?
p.s. itemList i used in my action class is a HashMap... does that matter?

Answer (score 1):

Using map is OK with collection-backed components. I think there's couple of problems with your code.

First in you action configuration you have set the root object to your `itemList`, this way only content of the list will be converted to json so you can't refer to the list itself in your autocompleter.

Second you have to set the `href` attribute for your autocompleter and set the `remoteUrl` as it's value. So your code could be like:

```
<package name="json" namespace="/" extends="json-default">
    <action name="test" class="testClass" method="populate">
        <result type="json"/>
    </action>
</package>
```

In your autompleter:

```
<s:form id="frm_demo" theme="simple" action="test2">
<s:url id="remoteurl" action="test" />         
<sj:autocompleter   href="%{remoteurl}"
                    id="lst"
                    name="lst"
                    list="itemList"
                    listValue="name"
                    listKey="id"
                    selectBox="true"/> 
    <s:submit value="submit"/>
</s:form>
```

See if that works.

Answer (score 0):

I think your code is ok,Just remove this code

```
<param name="contentType">text/html</param>
```